# How do I move a word to the end of line in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have a code like this:

```
Kuu(ij,mn)=-H1/A1/AA2*R0(ij,mn)*DA1Y*DQ66Y+...
H1/A1/AAA2*R0(ij,mn)*Q66*DA1Y*DA2Y-...
1/H1/AA1/AA2*H2*R0(ij,mn)*Q66*DA1Y^2+...
1/AA1/H1*DH2X*Q11*RX(ij,mn)-...
1/AAA1*H2/H1*Q11*RX(ij,mn)*DA1X+...
1/H1/AA1/A2*H2*Q11*RX(ij,mn)*DA2X;
```

I want to move "H1" to the end of line. so it will become like this:

```
Kuu(ij,mn)=-1/A1/AA2*R0(ij,mn)*DA1Y*DQ66Y+...H1
1/A1/AAA2*R0(ij,mn)*Q66*DA1Y*DA2Y-...H1
1//AA1/AA2*H2*R0(ij,mn)*Q66*DA1Y^2+...H1
1/AA1/*DH2X*Q11*RX(ij,mn)-...H1
1/AAA1*H2/*Q11*RX(ij,mn)*DA1X+...H1
1//AA1/A2*H2*Q11*RX(ij,mn)*DA2X;H1
```

Comment: Select, Press Ctrl+X, move to the end of the line and press Ctrl+V?

Comment: @Seth And if the file has several thousand lines to fix?

Comment: Are you sure you want "word", because H1 isn't a word? Don't you mean strings? If it's words, it's very different solution to simply strings.

Comment: In the first and second lines of your example, you’re not *moving* the word “H1”, you’re moving the “H” and copying the “1”. And what do you want to happen to a line that doesn’t contain “H1”? or that contains it multiple times?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### I want to move the word "H1" to the end of line

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^(.*)\bH1\b(.*)$`.
- Set "Replace with" to `\1\2H1`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

Before:

```
Kuu(ij,mn)=-H1/A1/AA2*R0(ij,mn)*DA1Y*DQ66Y+...
H1/A1/AAA2*R0(ij,mn)*Q66*DA1Y*DA2Y-...
1/H1/AA1/AA2*H2*R0(ij,mn)*Q66*DA1Y^2+...
1/AA1/H1*DH2X*Q11*RX(ij,mn)-...
1/AAA1*H2/H1*Q11*RX(ij,mn)*DA1X+...
1/H1/AA1/A2*H2*Q11*RX(ij,mn)*DA2X;
```

After:

```
Kuu(ij,mn)=-/A1/AA2*R0(ij,mn)*DA1Y*DQ66Y+...H1
/A1/AAA2*R0(ij,mn)*Q66*DA1Y*DA2Y-...H1
1//AA1/AA2*H2*R0(ij,mn)*Q66*DA1Y^2+...H1
1/AA1/*DH2X*Q11*RX(ij,mn)-...H1
1/AAA1*H2/*Q11*RX(ij,mn)*DA1X+...H1
1//AA1/A2*H2*Q11*RX(ij,mn)*DA2X;H1
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: Your regular expression does not treat `H1` as a word, and so it will be moved even if part of a longer word like `GAH1`. You probably need some `\b`s in there, if Notepad++ supports it.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition True, but it meets the requirements of the question. And in the examples there are no proper word boundaries surrounding H1

Comment: The question is _"How do I move a word to the end of line in notepad++?"_

Comment: @BoundaryImposition H1 is not a word (by any normal definition of a word) in the examples given in the question.

Comment: I disagree; in all examples given, it is surrounded by non-alphanumeric entities, thus meeting all common definitions of the term "word" in a context such as this. We will have to agree to disagree (at least until the OP clarifies their requirement). Good day.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Fair enough. The OP did accept my answer so presumably he is happy :)

Comment: It is likely he hasn't tried it with counter-examples.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition there, fixed.

Comment: @Braiam: Please do not modify people's questions to match answers without their permission. Rolled back.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Actually, I edited the question title to match the question body, H1, H2 and H3 aren't words. Calling them words isn't useful. BTW, nice argument there "do not modify people's questions to match answers without their permission", yet they accepted this answer...

Comment: @Braiam: I've already addressed both of those points. They are certainly words in a sense, and we have no counter-examples to show what should happen when the input contains, e.g. `GAH1`. The OP by definition is the least qualified to determine the total correctness of an answer; if the OP just ran this answer over their limited example input then yes it will appear to be correct. We should not modify the question until we _know_ completely what the OP wants. Maybe they do just want to match any substring! But maybe they don't.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Answer updated to use `\b` word boundaries.

Comment: Am I the only one who noticed that the output presented here in this answer does not match the example output in the question?  (And am I the only one who cares?)

Comment: @G-Man Hmm. Well spotted. Lines 1 & 2 is different. My guess is that the OP made a mistake, as my example output is correct if `H1` is moved to the end of every line in the input as was requested.